# YiiMailer duplicate subject and to address

Tags: yii, email, yii-extensions

I'm using YiiMailer to send my emails and I'm getting duplicate "subject lines" and also "To" fields.

```
$mail = new YiiMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
        $mail->Mailer='smtps';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure= 'tls';
        $mail->Username = "username";
        $mail->Password = "password";
        $mail->setFrom(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'], 'Administrator');
        $mail->setTo('an@emailaddress.com', 'Mr Administrator');
        $mail->setSubject('This is my subject');
        $mail->setBody('hello, this is my Email');
```

When I send the `subject` will read "This is my subject This is my subject" and I can see the `To` field has an@emailaddress.com; an@emailaddress.com;.

There is no loops or anything involved here. Just that code and It doesn't seem to be a one off either, it's in all of my websites emails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try exit after send mail function?

Comment: @Rorschach I just added `if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "success";
    exit(0); 
   }` and the same thing still happened

Comment: Can you try simple mailer? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer its same you are using in Yii. Just check if it is working or not, if it works may be problem with your server or you have to start debugging in extension :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that removing the line

`$mail->Mailer='smtps';`

stopped this error. This was happening in all my my mail correspondences and that line for some reason seemed to stop the duplicate issue (for some reason). Maybe it will help others too.